# При установке Skeeks cms (Yii2) у меня не отображаются картинки. Как можно настроить Document root на Open Server?

Tags: php, yii2, apache

Как это делается в хостинге я разобрался... Но в Open Servere  у меня не получается.

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName demo.ru
   DocumentRoot /path/to/demo.ru/frontend/web/

   <Directory "/path/to/demo.ru/frontend/web/">
       # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
       RewriteEngine on
       # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
       RewriteRule . index.php

       # use index.php as index file
       DirectoryIndex index.php

       # ...other settings...
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Куда нужно прописывать ? В Конфиг Apache или в корне проекта Yii2 создав файл htaccess &

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В настройках OpenServer на вкладке Домены нужно установить "Управление доменами" на "Ручное + Автопоиск" и на этой же вкладке добавить домен и DocumentRoot для него